# Want to get sum of 2 different columns from 2 different tables and want to display final sum

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    SUM(p.price + c.price) AS product_weekly_total 
FROM t_product_purchase p
LEFT JOIN 
    t_coupon_purchase c on c.storepkid=p.storepkid ";
WHERE 
    (p.purchasedatetime BETWEEN '2014-12-27 00:00:01' AND '2015-01-02 23:59:59') OR
    (c.purchasedatetime BETWEEN '2014-12-27 00:00:01' AND '2015-01-02 23:59:59')
GROUP BY 
    p.storepkid
ORDER BY  
    product_weekly_total DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

I want to get top 5 highest total records with sum of price and cprice fields. But above query is giving me wrong amounts in result.

If I remove 't_coupon_purchase' table from above query and fire query using just 't_product_purchase' then it is giving me correct result with correct amount.

Please let me know what wrong I am doing in my query or should I write it in other way for that I am not aware. Please provide some help on this.

---- EDIT - 01JAN2015 ---- 
SQL fiddle for my query
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d4523/8

Here I have mentioned total of each storeid so it will helpful to compare with query result.

5 = 67 + 68 + 115 = 250

1 = 57 + 50 + 75 + 66 = 248

3 = 70 + 144 = 214

2 = 23 + 100 + 22 + 27 = 172

4 = 15 + 7 + 105 = 127

9 = 34

7 = 33

Comment: Could you post some sample data, the expected result, and what you're getting instead? Otherwise, we can't tell what's wrong about the results.

Comment: the join is creating a one to many relationship causing the amounts to be artificially inflated.  Given this is mySQL, you have to run the sums as sub queries independent of eachother to get the proper result.  other RDBMS would allow you to do this via window'd sets. keyword `OVER`, but mySQL will rely on subqueries or two inline views.

Comment: ok, I am posting result data within couple of minutes. thank you

Comment: @KAhir try to post rows with actual values and expected results. Best would be to create an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with the data so that other users can try and write queries to give you the results you want.

Comment: @McAdam331, I agree and will post data in SQL fiddle.

Comment: Why are you ignoring results purchased at midnight? And why is 1 248 instead of 314?? (Likewise for 4 [127 instead of 232])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query works for me.

```
SELECT t.storepkid, SUM(t.price) AS product_weekly_total
FROM 
(
    SELECT storepkid AS storepkid, price AS price 
    FROM t_product_purchase 
    WHERE purchasedatetime BETWEEN '2014-12-27 00:00:01' AND '2015-01-02 23:59:59' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT storepkid, price FROM t_coupon_purchase
    WHERE purchasedatetime BETWEEN '2014-12-27 00:00:01' AND '2015-01-02 23:59:59' 
) t
GROUP BY storepkid
ORDER BY product_weekly_total DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

SQL fiddle is available at this link : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f269b/46

Comment: Really the best solution for the problem given.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think there is a typo on your 5th line `t_coupon_purchase c on c.storeid=p.storeid ";`. The `";` should not be there.

Also, your constraints in the dates should have only one `OR`. The code is not executed because after your second `OR`, there is no other constraint.

Since you are LEFT JOINing you might be adding a number with a non-matching NULL coming from the LEFT JOINed table. Also, I don't think you can order the results as you do it in your query. Can you try the following and see what you get?

```
select storeid, product_weekly_total from 
(
SELECT 
    p.storeid, SUM(coalesce(p.price,0) + coalesce(c.cprice,0)) AS product_weekly_total 
FROM t_product_purchase p
LEFT JOIN 
    t_coupon_purchase c on c.storeid=p.storeid
WHERE 
    (p.purchasedate BETWEEN '2014-12-27' AND '2015-01-03') OR
    (c.cpurchasedate BETWEEN '2014-12-27' AND '2015-01-03')
GROUP BY 
    p.storeid
) as X
ORDER BY  
    product_weekly_total DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

So you are actually ordering the end result of the sum.

Thanks

**EDIT**
From your datamodel seen in your fiddle, the lines:

```
(11, 7, 33.00, '2015-12-01 01:01:01'),
(12, 1, 75.00, '2015-12-01 07:07:57'),
(13, 5, 68.00, '2015-12-01 22:22:00'),
(14, 9, 34.00, '2015-12-01 09:06:00'),
(15, 2, 27.00, '2015-12-01 17:06:00');
```

Would not be returned as the date is december 1st 2015.

Comment: Thank you for your response but no data are returned when I fired above query.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add one more mistake in your code. Can you check again. Your code was not ran, you had 2 ORs whereas you needed only 1.

Comment: No luck yet... still giving no records. Thanks again

Comment: Hi your date format for 2015 is different. It reads 2015-12-01 which is dec 2015.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f269b/3 - I corrected dates but still no luck so please check once again and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Join only what you want to join. Here you want to join product purchases of the week with coupon purchases of the week. But what you do join is any product purchase with any coupon purchase (where at least one of the couple must be purchased in the given week). So instead aggregate your product purchases and your coupon purchases and then join.

```
select
  coalesce(p.storeid,c.storeid) as storeid,
  coalesce(p.price,0) + coalesce(c.price,0) as product_weekly_total
from
(
  select storeid, sum(price) as price
  from t_product_purchase
  where purchasedate between '2014-12-27' and '2015-01-03'
  group by storeid
) p
full outer join
(
  select storeid, sum(cprice) as price
  from t_coupon_purchase
  where cpurchasedate between '2014-12-27' and '2015-01-03'
  group by storeid
) c on c.storeid = p.storeid
order by product_weekly_total desc 
limit 5;
```

I am using a full outer join here to also get stores having purchases in the week in only in one of the tables.

EDIT: I made two mistakes. One thing is I did `p.price + c.price`, but the summands can be NULL, so it must be `coalesce(p.price,0) + coalesce(c.price,0)` instead. I've changed that in the query above. The other thing is that MySQL doesn't support full outer joins. I don't change this in above query, so as to keep the query readable. Here is how to change it to mimic a full outer join in MySQL: `A full outer join B` is `A left outer join B union A right outer join B`. So:

```
select storepkid, product_weekly_total
from
(
  select
    coalesce(p.storepkid,c.storepkid) as storepkid,
    coalesce(p.price,0) + coalesce(c.price,0) as product_weekly_total
  from
  (
    select storepkid, sum(price) as price
    from t_product_purchase
    where purchasedatetime BETWEEN '2014-12-27 00:00:01' AND '2015-01-02 23:59:59'
    group by storepkid
  ) p 
  left outer join
  (
    select storepkid, sum(price) as price
    from t_coupon_purchase
    where purchasedatetime BETWEEN '2014-12-27 00:00:01' AND '2015-01-02 23:59:59'
    group by storepkid
  ) c on c.storepkid = p.storepkid
  union
  select
    coalesce(p.storepkid,c.storepkid) as storepkid,
    coalesce(p.price,0) + coalesce(c.price,0) as product_weekly_total
  from
  (
    select storepkid, sum(price) as price
    from t_product_purchase
    where purchasedatetime BETWEEN '2014-12-27 00:00:01' AND '2015-01-02 23:59:59'
    group by storepkid
  ) p 
  right outer join
  (
    select storepkid, sum(price) as price
    from t_coupon_purchase
    where purchasedatetime BETWEEN '2014-12-27 00:00:01' AND '2015-01-02 23:59:59'
    group by storepkid
  ) c on c.storepkid = p.storepkid
) all_results
order by product_weekly_total desc 
limit 5;
```

The fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f269b/54.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But as @McAdam331 said, I will post data in SQL fiddle after sometime.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f269b/6 - This is SQL fiddle based on your query. It was giving error with FULL OUTER JOIN so I used LEFT OUTER JOIN but giving wrong result yet. Please check and provide your help.

Comment: Thanks for the SQL fiddle. You are right, MySQL doesn't support full outer joins and I forgot to replace NULLS with zeros in my claculation. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your all efforts. For some reason, your query is still not giving proper result but problem is resolved using my query. Thanks again

Comment: I tried my query with your SQL fiddle and it is giving the same results. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f269b/55 . However, I was thinking too complicated. As you treat product purchases and coupon purchases equally, there is no need for such complex query. Yours is much better.

Comment: My mistake... yes your query is giving same result. Sorry for that.